# Prevent Multisite from creating sample page, sample post and sample comments

Tags: customization, multisite

How do I prevent the creation of these when creating a new Multisite?

Everytime I create a new multisite this gets created:

- Hello World
- Sample Page
- A sample Comment

I tried adding this to the `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'delete_wordpress_defaults', 100, 1 );

function delete_wordpress_defaults(){

// 'Hello World!' post
wp_delete_post( 1, true );

// 'Sample page' page
wp_delete_post( 2, true );
}
```

It still created Hello world and Sample page. And I don't know how to disable the sample comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you [create a new site with multisite](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/) WP does not automatically change the context. So your action is added to the current site, not the new site. You have to switch first. Like this:

```
add_action ('wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse296303_delete_wordpress_defaults', 100, 1);

function wpse296303_delete_wordpress_defaults ($blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta) {
  // Switch to the newly created blog
  switch_to_blog ($blog_id);
  // Delete 'Hello World!' post
  wp_delete_post (1, true);
  // Delete 'Sample page' page
  wp_delete_post (2, true);
  // Delete 'Sample comment' page
  wp_delete_comment (1, true)
  }
```

I'm not sure if the ID of the default comment is 1, so you'd have to check that.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand. Do I have to do something else than adding this to my functions.php file? And creating a new site will not create this? What do you mean with "You have to switch first"?
I tried adding this code (checked that comment id 1 is correct) and added the ending ";" after comment line. It did not work, I got a white screen when creating a new site. The site was created, but the sample post/pages/comments where there!

Comment: Code is always executed in the context of the current site. So if you put the snippet in the `functions.php` of site A, which is active when you create site B, it will be executed on site A and delete the posts on site A. So you have to switch to site B first then and the delete the posts. If you put the snippet in the `functions.php` of site B it will only be executed after the theme was activated. That might be after the posts have been created. You can use [`switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) after switchting the blog to activate the functions file.

Answer (score 0):

best luck i got:

/public_html/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-meta.php
\public_html\wp-admin\includes\schema.php
/public_html\wp-admin\includes\upgrade.php

deleteing code of post comment page url etc.
5.1.11

yes after update they might be restored but you will know where to fix up again.

Comment: Modifying core code is a bad idea. As you've pointed out, your changes will be undone when WordPress is updated.

Comment: as i noticed those files unchanged 3-4 years

Comment: That may be true, but every WordPress update will reset them anyway.

Comment: as there are no info how this is best what i found over weeks of reserch

Comment: you can always make backup of both. edited and original file. and if will change you will see where what to edit.